# Test for the influence of a manipulation on multiple dependent measurements (order effects, multiple comparisons)

Tags: r, mixed-model, multiple-comparisons, dependent-variable

I have a dataset which looks like this:

```
data_ex <- data.frame( pnum = rep(1:10, each=2),
                   manipulation =  rep(1:2, each=10),
                   order_manipulation = c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1),
                   man_onoff = c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1),
                   score_a = floor(runif(20, min=0, max=101)),
                   score_b = floor(runif(20, min=0, max=101)),
                   score_c = floor(runif(20, min=0, max=101)),
                   score_x = floor(runif(20, min=0, max=101)),
                   score_y = floor(runif(20, min=0, max=101)),
                   score_z = floor(runif(20, min=0, max=101)))
```

Each participant is tested twice: either with a manipulation or without a manipulation (f.e. mood induction or medication). There are three **types** of manipulations, type 1, type 2 or type 3. We also know the **order** of the presentation of the manipulation.

The main research question here is: which of the three manipulations is most strongly predictive of which of the 6 outcome measures (a,b,c,x,y,z), while controlling for order of manipulation?

I don't think a correlation matrix would help, since I'd like to test against each type of medication. Nor testing every manipulation type separately on each outcome measurement, since that would inflate the amount of tests completely and we'll have to correct for all the multiple comparisons.

Is there a way to answer my question with one statistical test (preferably in R)?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you are looking for a single combination of manipulation and outcome measure, e.g., manipulation type 2 most strongly predicts outcome c?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to be able to say, manipulation type 2 predicts outcome c *stronger than* manipulation type 1 or 3

Comment: But what other statements would you like to make? Do you basically want to determine _for each outcome measure_ which of the three manipulations best predicts it?

Comment: Yes that's correct, I'm sorry I was not clear! I guess in this case I'd end up with 6 simple regressions (e.g. `data_ex %>% dplyr::filter(man_onoff==1) %>% lm(score_a ~manipulation*order_manipulation)` ;  `data_ex %>% dplyr::filter(man_onoff==1) %>% lm(score_b ~manipulation*order_manipulation)` etc. etc. But in my real data, I have more than just 6 outcome measurements, and I would like to avoid having to correct for the multiple comparisons I'd end up with....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think what you describe can be done while avoiding multiple comparison correction. With many outcome measures, on average some of your hypothesis tests will turn out significant even if none of the treatments have any effect. Correction for multiple comparisons is designed to protect you from drawing the (false) conclusion that your treatment does have some effect.

Since you are fitting a linear model in your comment, I will assume that your outcome data are actually normally distributed, not uniformly as in your data example.

Assuming additionally that the scale (including variance) of the outcome measures is the same (or that they can be rescaled so that they are), you **can** do a single test to see which treatment has the biggest effect overall.

One option here would be a classical MANOVA:

```
# set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(12345)
# generate sample data
data_ex <- data.frame( pnum = rep(1:10, each=2),
                   manipulation =  rep(1:2, each=10),
                   order_manipulation = c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1),
                   man_onoff = c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1),
                   score_a = floor(runif(20, min=0, max=101)),
                   score_b = floor(runif(20, min=0, max=101)),
                   score_c = floor(runif(20, min=0, max=101)),
                   score_x = floor(runif(20, min=0, max=101)),
                   score_y = floor(runif(20, min=0, max=101)),
                   score_z = floor(runif(20, min=0, max=101)))
# recode manipulation and man_onoff into a single variable
data_ex$manipulation_new <- factor(data_ex$manipulation * data_ex$man_onoff)
# manova requires a matrix on the left side of the formula
depvars <- as.matrix(data_ex[,grep('^score_', names(data_ex))])
# run manova
my_manova <- manova( depvars ~ manipulation_new*order_manipulation, data = data_ex)
# check results
summary(my_manova)
```

If you find a significant effect overall you could then follow up with suitable post-hoc tests. Two caveats:

- MANOVA would be sensitive to effects in both directions (e.g., if the
  treatment makes an outcome much worse that would also show up)
- MANOVA has some specific assumptions (in particular multivariate normality    of dependent variables), **and** is quite sensitive to
  deviations    from these assumptions.

Another option would be to run this as a linear mixed model:

```
# set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(12345)
# generate sample data
data_ex <- data.frame( pnum = rep(1:10, each=2),
                       manipulation =  rep(1:2, each=10),
                       order_manipulation = c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1),
                       man_onoff = c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1),
                       score_a = rnorm(20),
                       score_b = rnorm(20),
                       score_c = rnorm(20),
                       score_x = rnorm(20),
                       score_y = rnorm(20),
                       score_z = rnorm(20))
# make this a bit more realistic
id_intercept <- rnorm(10) # subject random effects 
measure_intercept <- rnorm(6) # measure random effects
manip2_effect <- abs(rnorm(6)) # all effects of manipulation are positive
data_ex[,grep('^score_', names(data_ex))] <- data_ex[,grep('^score_', names(data_ex))] + id_intercept[data_ex$pnum]
data_ex[,grep('^score_', names(data_ex))] <- sweep(data_ex[,grep('^score_', names(data_ex))], 2, measure_intercept, "+")
data_ex[data_ex$manipulation == 2 & data_ex$man_onoff == 1,grep('^score_', names(data_ex))] <- 
 sweep(data_ex[data_ex$manipulation == 2 & data_ex$man_onoff == 1,grep('^score_', names(data_ex))], 2, manip2_effect, "+")
# collect outcome variables
outcomes <- grep('^score_', names(data_ex), value = TRUE)
outcome_names <- sub('^score_','',outcomes)
# reshape data frame into long format
data_long <- reshape(data_ex, varying = list(score = outcomes), direction = 'long', times = outcome_names, idvar = c('pnum', 'man_onoff'))
# rename outcome variable
names(data_long)[grep('^score_a$', names(data_long))] <- 'score'
names(data_long)[grep('^time$', names(data_long))] <- 'measure'
# recode manipulation and man_onoff into a single (factor) variable
data_long$manipulation_new <- factor(data_long$manipulation * data_ex$man_onoff)
# load lme4
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest) # assuming you need p-values
my_mixed_model <- lmer(score ~ manipulation_new + (1 | measure) + (1 | pnum), data = data_long)
anova(my_mixed_model) # any effect of any manipulation?
summary(my_mixed_model) # which manipulation is most effective
```

Again, if you find any significant effects you could then follow up with appropriate post-hoc tests. Note that one advantage of the linear mixed model approach is that it deals easily with missing data, whereas MANOVA requires complete cases (at least per session). On the other hand, there is much debate regarding the validity of p-values for the mixed-model approach (even when ignoring the current debate regarding the use of p-values generally).